# Endeca wild carded search - autocorrection/dym combination

Tags: search, endeca, oracle-commerce

Performing wild carding on wrongly spelled term will not allow autocorrection/dym be calculated for the non wild carded term.

Example:

- Searching **iphont** will be autocorected to **iphone** and return
  results.
- Searching for **iphont*** will not get corrected and return any results or
  suggestions.

I understand there is an processing order but is there an OOB way to make this work instead of doing 2 queries (wild carded query, if no results regular query)?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation wild carded searches don't support several search features like autocorrection, dym, phrased search, thesaurus etc.